# Check which type of object List<?> contains

Tags: java, generics

`List` contains the object type, but I need to check if that object is of type `A` or `B`:

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();

List<A> aL = new ArrayList<A>();
List<B> bL = new ArrayList<B>();
```

How can I check whether `List` contains `A` objects or `B` objects?

Here is the code:

```
    SegmentDetailInfo segmentDetailInfo  = new SegmentDetailInfo();
    segmentDetailInfo.setSeg_Id("1");

    SegReqInfoBean segReqInfoBean  = new SegReqInfoBean();
    segReqInfoBean.setPageName("homepage");

    List<SegmentDetailInfo> rhsList1 = new ArrayList<SegmentDetailInfo>();
    rhsList1.add(segmentDetailInfo);

    List<SegReqInfoBean> rhsList2 = new ArrayList<SegReqInfoBean>();
    rhsList2.add(segReqInfoBean);

    doProspecListCompareCheck(rhsList1);
    doProspecListCompareCheck(rhsList2);

}

private static void doProspecListCompareCheck(Object rhsList) {
     if (rhsList instanceof List<SegmentDetailInfo>) //wrong Check
         //DoTHIS
     else if(rhsList instanceof List<SegReqInfoBean>)   //wrong Check       
         //Do THIS       

}
```

========================================================

```
    SegmentDetailInfo segmentDetailInfo  = new SegmentDetailInfo();
    segmentDetailInfo.setSeg_Id("1");

    SegReqInfoBean segReqInfoBean1  = new SegReqInfoBean();
    segReqInfoBean1.setPageName("Home");

    List<SegmentDetailInfo> rhsList1 = new ArrayList<SegmentDetailInfo>();
    rhsList1.add(segmentDetailInfo);

    List<SegReqInfoBean> rhsList2 = new ArrayList<SegReqInfoBean>();      
    rhsList2.add(segReqInfoBean1);

    String Homepage="homepage";

    doProspecListCompareCheck(Homepage);
    doProspecListCompareCheck(rhsList2);
    doProspecListCompareCheck(rhsList2);


private static void doProspecListCompareCheck(Object rhsListObj) {
         List<String> rhsStrList = new ArrayList<String>();
         List<SegReqInfoBean> segReqInfoBeanList = new ArrayList<SegReqInfoBean>();
         List<SegmentDetailInfo> segmentDetailInfoList = new ArrayList<SegmentDetailInfo>();


     if (rhsListObj != null && rhsListObj instanceof List) {

         if (((List<SegmentDetailInfo>) rhsListObj).get(0) instanceof SegmentDetailInfo){

                System.out.println("SegmentDetailInfo loading");
                segmentDetailInfoList = (List<SegmentDetailInfo>) rhsListObj;     
        }
         else if(((List<SegReqInfoBean>) rhsListObj).get(0) instanceof SegReqInfoBean){

                System.out.println("SegReqInfoBean loading");   
                segReqInfoBeanList = (List<SegReqInfoBean>) rhsListObj;
         }          

     }else if ( rhsListObj != null && rhsListObj instanceof String) {

         rhsStrList.add(rhsListObj.toString());

     }

}
```

Comment: Type erasure prevents you from doing that.

Comment: In this *very narrow* scenario, you could probably check `((List)rhsList).get(0) instanceof SegReqInfoBean`.  It requires that you have something in the list, otherwise there is no way to tell.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generics only provide compile-time checks. At runtime, they are completely gone. This is known as type erasure. So at runtime, your code looks like this:

```
    List rhsList1 = new ArrayList();
    rhsList1.add(segmentDetailInfo);

    List rhsList2 = new ArrayList();
    rhsList2.add(segReqInfoBean);

    doProspecListCompareCheck(rhsList1);
    doProspecListCompareCheck(rhsList2);

}
private static void doProspecListCompareCheck(Object rhsList) {


     if (rhsList instanceof List) //wrong Check
         //DoTHIS
     else if(rhsList instanceof List)   //wrong Check       
         //Do THIS       

}
```

Distinguishing two generic objects by their generic parameter is simply not something you can do in Java.

Answer (score 27):

One way you can do it is by comparing first `Object` inside the `List` :

```
private static void doProspecListCompareCheck(List rhsList)
{
    if(rhsList != null && !rhsList.isEmpty())
    {
        if (rhsList.get(0) instanceof SegReqInfoBean)
        {

        }
        else if(rhsList.get(0) instanceof SegmentDetailInfo)    
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably should change the parameter type to `List`.

Comment: @clav Yes since we always want to receive a °List°, at least!

Comment: @Shivababa it looks ok to me but pretty odd it you want to do almost everything with one function. In this case I would more suggest mixing this solution with the answer provided by StonyZhang below

Comment: This wouldn't work in case we needed somewhere List<Void>

Answer (score 1):

```
for (Object aList : list) {
    Class cls = aList.getClass();
    System.out.println("The type of the object is: " + cls.getName());
}
```

This seems to work for me. This will not only detect if any index is of type A or B, but detects every type.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the list is non-empty you can do rhsList.get(0) instanceof  SegReqInfobean

If the list may be empty you could start by inserting an object of the correct type and then remember that index 0 stores a dummy object, so remove it before processing (or just start processing the list at index 0). Generics are just a compile time convenience.  You can't use the generic type at runtime as you discovered.